# Running MySQL with QuickPHP

Tags: php, mysql

Context: I work at a college and wanted to get students involved in PHP and MySQL development. The IT technicians have configured the systems such that I can’t use packages like XAMPP, USBWebserver or Server2Go.  I have tried QuickPHP and that works fine in the environment.

My question is how do I get MySQL running with QuickPHP? I've checked the notes on QuickPHP web but its slightly vague. I downloaded the MySQL Community Edition zip but I am at a loss on what to do next. Bearing in mind I cannot and nor will the students be able to install anything due to restrictive access rights.

Hope that makes sense?

Link to QuickPHP: http://www.zachsaw.com/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger

Comment: Is PHP the right choice? It's not exactly easy to grasp all the web concepts right. And with incoherent and illogical PHP full of quirks its even harder. How about starting with something more consistent like Python.

Comment: Why not ask IT technicians to remove the restrictions or at least install the things you need for you?

Comment: Oh and btw, this belongs rather to SerferFault.com

Comment: @Pankucins, admins at colleges are typically kind of BOFH

Comment: @Pankucins - the IT technicians are not very friendly to say in kinder words. They won't even install Greenfoot which is free. Had to run the portable of that.

Comment: @ Ondra Žižka should I ask at ServerFault.com ?

Comment: What if you were to use a live-cd type of setup ? U dont install anything, just pop in a cd /  dvd and reboot

Comment: @MarcoZen good idea, I tried it but BIOS is locked :(

Comment: How about SQLite instead of MySQL? MySQL is an exteral application that needs to be installed, but SQLite is embedded, meaning no extra installation is required.

Comment: @JoryGeerts did think of that solution but command prompt is blocked.

Comment: I've read PHP can use MSAccess db. So that seems like a likely option, but when I enable the it in the ini, QUICKPHP says it can't load the dynamic library - any ideas?

Comment: @user1639423 you don't need a command prompt to use SQLite (or MySQL, or ...) from PHP, just `new PDO("sqlite://db.sqlite");` and there is your database.

Answer (score 0):

Really, don't.

While it is possible to use PHP as a general purpose programming language, producing websites is where it shines. By all means point your students to an installation like QuickPHP to give your students the opportunity to test their code offline and on their own machines. But providing access to shared server will let them run PHP in a far more suitable environment and teach them lots more transferable skills. It's not hard to set up a simple server running Linux or BSD, using samba or web-dav for accessing the source code.

If your support staff have configured the machines such that they cannot be used for their primary purpose (i.e. educating users about computers - how they work, how to look after them, use them effectively and how they break) then there is something *very, very wrong* with the management of your institution.

Not only is this to the disadvantage of your students - it also means that the admin of the machines is far from cost effective.